# iceCandidate got failed for webRTC in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, chat, webrtc, videochat

I did sample application for Video communication in webRTC.Its working fine for Chrome but in Firefox its giving iceCandidatefailed error. Can you please suggest me. This is the code having some problem.
Thanks in advance.

```
function onicecandidate(iceCandidate) {
    debugger;
        console.log("ice candidate send to room ", iceCandidate);
        // send candidates to other guy
        if (!peerConnection || !event || !event.candidate) return;
        var candidate = event.candidate;
        debugger;
        var data = {
            'type': 'candidate', 'label':candidate.sdpMLineIndex, 'sdpMid':candidate.sdpMid, 'candidate':candidate.candidate
        };
        socket.emit('message', data);
    };
```

Comment: Can you please share more of the code of you application? Particularly the parts that create a peer connect, add user media, and deal with offer/answer. And, also, who reports this error? Do you see it in the console? Or maybe the error callback is called?

Comment: We are able to created "initiater", "peer" and when I was trying to "createOffer" sdp not going properly, In console we got sdpMid:"". We are not geting any error.